# Video embed displays HTML code instead of video

Tags: plugin-duktvideos

We're using Dukt Videos to display a video on [this page](http://www.adventurekent.org/services/schools/ks1-2/adventure-kent-in-action) of our website. However, the video no longer appears on the page and just shows the HTML for the iframe.

Any idea what has happened?

Comment: Twig raw filter?

Comment: Ah, just seen this is for Duke plugin which I don't think needs raw.

Comment: Can you post your template code? It looks like the html for the video is being outputted as a plain text string.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to add the twig raw filter to your field variable. This will allow twig to interpret the data as safe HTML rather than just plain text.

```
{{ myFieldVariable|raw }}
```

Lear more about the raw filter here: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html

Comment: Fwiw, if you're using a plain text field for admin to drop in embed code (e.g., not using duktvideos) and see the code output as text, this fix applies there, too.